# How to arrange feature matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, datamatrix

I'm trying to arrange a feature matrix of size (1425 x 15) where each column represents the natural frequency of each sensor and each row represents a single data file. However, I keep on getting the same values in each column and the next value is printed to the next row. How would I be able to rearrange the feature matrix?

I tried to form a code which can be found below, but, I don't know what my mistake in the code. I formed different codes but the results were still the same. Please find below the codes formed:

Code 1:

```
# Matrix array:
DataSizerow=0
DataSizecolumn=0
Data = np.zeros((1425,15))

# Forming a feature matrix from frequency, PSD and AutoCorrelation values:
        # Dataset.shape[1] represesnt the acceleration dataset column
        # List_Of_DataFrame_Feature = []
        # List_Of_DataFrame_Label = []
        Length_PSD_mean = len(x_axis_list_psd_filtered)
        print('Length of PSD values: ', Length_PSD_mean)
        if Length_PSD_mean > 1:
            for PSD_Mean in range(Length_PSD_mean):
                X_axis_values_psd_mean = mean(x_axis_list_psd_filtered)
        else:
            X_axis_values_psd_mean = x_axis_list_psd_filtered
        DataFrame_Feature = np.array(X_axis_values_psd_mean)
        DataFrame_Feature1 = np.array(x_axis_list_filtered)
        DataSizecolumn = DataSizecolumn + 1
        print('Data Size column: ',DataSizecolumn)
        Data[DataSizecolumn - 1] = DataFrame_Feature
        if DataSizecolumn in range(1, dataset.shape[1]):
            DataSizerow = DataSizerow + 1
            print('Data Size row: ', DataSizerow)
            Data[DataSizerow - 1] = DataFrame_Feature
        print('Sensor {0}'.format(k))
        print('Data Frame: ', Data)
```

Code 2:

```
        # Dataset.shape[0] represesnt the acceleration dataset row
        # Dataset.shape[1] represesnt the acceleration dataset column
        DataSizecolumn1 = 0
        DataSizerow1 = 0
        DataFrame1 = np.zeros((1426, 16))
        for DataSizecolumn1 in range(1, dataset.shape[1]):
            print('Data Size column: ', DataSizecolumn1)
            for DataSizerow1 in range(1, dataset.shape[0]):
                print('Data Size row: ', DataSizerow1)
                DataFrame1[DataSizerow1][DataSizecolumn1] = DataFrame_Feature
        print('Sensor {0}'.format(k))
        print('DataFrame: ', DataFrame1)
```

Code 3:

```
        # Dataset.shape[0] represesnt the acceleration dataset row
        # Dataset.shape[1] represesnt the acceleration dataset column
        DataSizecolumn2 = 0
        DataSizerow2 = 0
        DataFrame2 = np.zeros((1426, 16))
        for DataSizecolumn2 in range(1, dataset.shape[1]):
            print('Data Size column: ', DataSizecolumn2)
            DataFrame2[DataSizecolumn2] = DataFrame_Feature
            if DataSizecolumn2 == dataset.shape[1]:
                DataSizerow2 = DataSizerow2 + 1
                print('Data Size row: ', DataSizerow2)
                DataFrame2[DataSizerow2] = DataFrame_Feature
                if DataSizerow2 == dataset.shape[0]:
                    break
        print('Sensor {0}'.format(k))
        print('DataFrame: ', DataFrame2)
```

The expected result should be like the matrix below of single row:

```
          Sensor 1 | Sensor 2 | Sensor 3 | Sensor 4 | Sensor 5 | Sensor 6 | 
Data file     13   |   51.5   |    13    |   13     |    13    |    13    |
          Sensor 7 | Sensor 8 | Sensor 9 | Sensor 10 | Sensor 11 | Sensor 12 | 
Data file     8.5  |    14    |    20    |   18.6    |   9.5     |   39    |
          Sensor 13 | Sensor 14 | Sensor 15 | 
Data file     8.5   |    8.5    |    8.5    |
```

But the actual result is below:

```
          Sensor 1 | Sensor 2 | Sensor 3 | Sensor 4 | Sensor 5 | Sensor 6 | 
Data file     13   |   13     |    13    |   13     |    13    |    13    |
          Sensor 7 | Sensor 8 | Sensor 9 | Sensor 10 | Sensor 11 | Sensor 12 | 
Data file     13   |    13    |    13    |    13     |    13     |    13     |
          Sensor 13 | Sensor 14 | Sensor 15 | 
Data file     13    |    13     |    13     |
```

[Actual Feature matirx text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UDva.png)

Please find below the whole code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft
from scipy.signal import welch
import glob
import sys
from numpy import NaN, Inf, arange, isscalar, asarray, array
from statistics import mean
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

def peakdet(v, delta, x=None):
    """
    Converted from MATLAB script at http://billauer.co.il/peakdet.html

    Returns two arrays

    function [maxtab, mintab]=peakdet(v, delta, x)
    %PEAKDET Detect peaks in a vector
    %        [MAXTAB, MINTAB] = PEAKDET(V, DELTA) finds the local
    %        maxima and minima ("peaks") in the vector V.
    %        MAXTAB and MINTAB consists of two columns. Column 1
    %        contains indices in V, and column 2 the found values.
    %
    %        With [MAXTAB, MINTAB] = PEAKDET(V, DELTA, X) the indices
    %        in MAXTAB and MINTAB are replaced with the corresponding
    %        X-values.
    %
    %        A point is considered a maximum peak if it has the maximal
    %        value, and was preceded (to the left) by a value lower by
    %        DELTA.

    % Eli Billauer, 3.4.05 (Explicitly not copyrighted).
    % This function is released to the public domain; Any use is allowed.

    """
    maxtab = []
    mintab = []

    if x is None:
        x = arange(len(v))

    v = asarray(v)

    if len(v) != len(x):
        sys.exit('Input vectors v and x must have same length')

    if not isscalar(delta):
        sys.exit('Input argument delta must be a scalar')

    if delta <= 0:
        sys.exit('Input argument delta must be positive')

    mn, mx = Inf, -Inf
    mnpos, mxpos = NaN, NaN

    lookformax = True

    for i in arange(len(v)):
        this = v[i]
        if this > mx:
            mx = this
            mxpos = x[i]
        if this < mn:
            mn = this
            mnpos = x[i]

        if lookformax:
            if this < mx - delta:
                maxtab.append((mxpos, mx))
                mn = this
                mnpos = x[i]
                lookformax = False
        else:
            if this > mn + delta:
                mintab.append((mnpos, mn))
                mx = this
                mxpos = x[i]
                lookformax = True
    return array(maxtab), array(mintab)

# Definition to get values needed for the FFT plot:
def get_fft_values(y_values, T, N, f_s):
    f_values = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N//2)
    fft_values_ = fft(y_values)
    fft_values = 2.0/N * np.abs(fft_values_[0:N//2])
    return f_values, fft_values

# Definition to find the values of axis:
def findyaxis(y_axis_input, x, y):
    x = np.array(x)
    order = y.argsort()
    y = y[order]
    x = x[order]
    input = np.array(y_axis_input)
    return x[y.searchsorted(input, 'left')]

def merge(list1, list2):
    merged_list = [(list1[i], list2[i]) for i in range(0, len(list1))]
    return merged_list

def autocorr(x):
    result = np.correlate(x, x, mode='full')
    return result[len(result) // 2:]

def get_autocorr_values(y_values, T, N, f_s):
    autocorr_values = autocorr(y_values)
    x_values = np.array([T * jj for jj in range(0, N)])
    return x_values, autocorr_values

def signaltonoise(a, axis=0, ddof=0):
    """
    The signal - to - noise ratio of the input data. Returns the signal - to - noise ratio of `a`, here defined as the
    mean divided by the standard deviation.
    Parameters
    ----------
    a: array_like An array_like object containing the sample data.

    axis: int or None, optional.
    If axis is equal to None, the array is first ravel 'd. If axis is an
    integer, this is the axis over which to operate.Default is 0.

    ddof: int, optional.
    Degrees of freedom correction for standard deviation.Default is 0.

    Returns
    -------
    s2n: ndarray.
    The mean to standard deviation ratio(s) along `axis`, or 0 where the standard deviation is 0.
    """
    a = np.asanyarray(a)
    m = a.mean(axis)
    sd = a.std(axis=axis, ddof=ddof)
    return np.where(sd == 0, 0, m/sd)

def get_psd_values(y_values, T, N, f_s):
    f_values, psd_values = welch(y_values, fs=f_s)
    return f_values, psd_values

def smooth(y, box_pts):
    box = np.ones(box_pts)/box_pts
    y_smooth = np.convolve(y, box, mode='same')
    return y_smooth

# Assign folder to `folder`:
DataPathList = sorted(glob.glob('DataPath*.txt'), key = lambda z: (len(z)))
# DataSizerow = 0
# DataSizecolumn = 0
MaxDataSizerow = 1425
MaxDataSizecolumn = 15
Data = np.zeros((1426,15))
for fp in DataPathList:
    # Load spreadsheet:
    print('Opened file number: {}'.format(fp))
    dataset = np.loadtxt(fname=fp)
    print('The size matrix of Sensors Undamaged Scenario:', dataset.shape)
    print('The column size matrix of Sensors Undamaged Scenario:',dataset.shape[1])
    for k in range(1, dataset.shape[1]):
        # Create some time data to use for the plot:
        dt = 1

        # Getting the time period and frequency:
        t_n = 2
        N = 2192
        T_s = 0.00390625
        f_s = 256

        # Obtaining data in order to plot the graph:
        y = dataset[:,k]
        x = np.arange(0, len(y), dt)
        x1 = np.linspace(0, t_n, N)

        SNR = signaltonoise(y)
        print('Signal-to-Noise Ratio (SNR): ', SNR, 'dB')

        SR = 1/t_n
        SR1 = 1/T_s
        Nf = (SR)/2
        Nf1 = (SR1)/2

        # Plotting the acceleration-time graph:
        # plt.plot(x1, y)
        # plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
        # plt.ylabel('Acceleration (ms^-2)')
        # plt.title('Plot of Sensor {0}'.format(k))
        # # plt.show()
        # plt.show(block = False)
        # print('Plot of Sensor {0}'.format(k))
        # plt.pause(5)  # Pauses the program for 10 seconds
        # plt.close('all')

        ## Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)
        # Obtaining the Sampling frequency and time period:
        print('Period:', T_s, 's')
        print('Sampling Frequency: ', f_s, 'Hz')
        f_values, fft_values = get_fft_values(y, T_s, N, f_s)

        # Setting plot limits:
        ax = plt.gca()
        ax.set_ylim([min(fft_values), max(fft_values)])
        ax.set_xlim([min(f_values), max(f_values)])
        amp_index = np.array(fft_values)
        amp_index_max = max(amp_index)
        amp_index_min = min(amp_index)
        delta = (amp_index_max + amp_index_min)/2

        # Obtaining the amplitude values:
        maxtab, mintab = np.array(peakdet(amp_index, delta))
        amplitudes3 = maxtab
        y_axis_list = []
        for e in range(len(amplitudes3)):
            amplitude3 = amplitudes3[e]
            amplitude3final = amplitudes3[e][1]
            y_values = amplitude3final
            y_axis_list.append(y_values)
        x_axis = np.abs(f_values)
        x_axis_list = []
        for o in range(len(y_axis_list)):
            x_axis_values = findyaxis(y_axis_list[o], x_axis, fft_values)
            x_axis_list.append(x_axis_values)
        peaks = merge(x_axis_list, y_axis_list)
        print('Number of Peaks Coordinates: ', len(peaks))
        print('Peaks Coordinates: ', peaks)

        # Plotting the amplitude-frequency graph:
        # plt.plot(f_values, fft_values, linestyle='-', color='blue')
        # plt.scatter(x_axis_list, y_axis_list, marker='*', color='red', label='Peaks: {0}'.format(len(peaks)))
        # plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]', fontsize=16)
        # plt.ylabel('Amplitude', fontsize=16)
        # plt.title("Frequency domain of the signal {0}".format(k), fontsize=16)
        # plt.legend()
        # # plt.show()
        # plt.show(block = False)
        # print('Frequency domain with peaks of the signal {0}'.format(k))
        # plt.pause(5)  # Pauses the program for 10 seconds
        # plt.close('all')

        # Obtaining the PSD values:
        f_values, psd_values = get_psd_values(y, T_s, N, f_s)
        amp_psd_index = np.array(psd_values)
        amp_psd_index_max = max(amp_psd_index)
        amp_psd_index_min = min(amp_psd_index)
        psd_delta = (amp_psd_index_max + amp_psd_index_min) / 2
        maxtab, mintab = np.array(peakdet(amp_psd_index, psd_delta))
        amplitudes_psd = maxtab
        y_axis_list_psd = []
        for e in range(len(amplitudes_psd)):
            amplitude_psd = amplitudes_psd[e]
            amplitude_psd_final = amplitudes_psd[e][1]
            y_values_psd = amplitude_psd_final
            y_axis_list_psd.append(y_values_psd)
        x_axis_psd = np.abs(f_values)
        x_axis_list_psd = []
        for o in range(len(y_axis_list_psd)):
            x_axis_values_psd = findyaxis(y_axis_list_psd[o], x_axis_psd, psd_values)
            x_axis_list_psd.append(x_axis_values_psd)
        psd_peaks = merge(x_axis_list_psd, y_axis_list_psd)
        print('Number of PSD Peaks Coordinates: ', len(psd_peaks))
        print('PSD Peaks Coordinates: ', psd_peaks)

        # Plotting PSD-Frequency graph:
        # plt.plot(f_values, psd_values, linestyle='-', color='blue')
        # plt.scatter(x_axis_list_psd, y_axis_list_psd, marker='*', color='red', label='Peaks: {0}'.format(len(psd_peaks)))
        # plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
        # plt.ylabel('PSD [V**2 / Hz]')
        # plt.title("PSD of the signal {0}".format(k), fontsize=16)
        # plt.legend()
        # # plt.show()
        # plt.show(block = False)
        # print('PSD with peaks of the signal {0}'.format(k))
        # plt.pause(5)  # Pauses the program for 10 seconds
        # plt.close('all')

        # Obtaining AutoCorrelation values:
        t_values, autocorr_values = get_autocorr_values(y, T_s, N, f_s)
        amp_auto_corr_index = np.array(autocorr_values)
        amp_auto_corr_index_max = max(amp_auto_corr_index)
        amp_auto_corr_index_min = min(amp_auto_corr_index)
        auto_corr_delta = (amp_auto_corr_index_max + amp_auto_corr_index_min) / 2
        maxtab, mintab = np.array(peakdet(amp_auto_corr_index, auto_corr_delta))
        amplitudes_auto_corr = maxtab
        y_axis_list_auto_corr = []
        for e in range(len(amplitudes_auto_corr)):
            amplitude_auto_corr = amplitudes_auto_corr[e]
            amplitude_auto_corr_final = amplitudes_auto_corr[e][1]
            y_values_auto_corr = amplitude_auto_corr_final
            y_axis_list_auto_corr.append(y_values_auto_corr)
        x_axis_auto_corr = np.abs(t_values)
        x_axis_list_auto_corr = []
        for o in range(len(y_axis_list_auto_corr)):
            x_axis_values_auto_corr = findyaxis(y_axis_list_auto_corr[o], x_axis_auto_corr, autocorr_values)
            x_axis_list_auto_corr.append(x_axis_values_auto_corr)
        auto_corr_peaks = merge(x_axis_list_auto_corr, y_axis_list_auto_corr)
        print('Number of AutoCorrelation Peaks Coordinates: ', len(auto_corr_peaks))
        print('AutoCorrelation Peaks Coordinates: ', auto_corr_peaks)

        # Plotting Autocorrelation-Time delay graph
        # plt.plot(t_values, autocorr_values, linestyle='-', color='blue')
        # plt.scatter(x_axis_list_auto_corr, y_axis_list_auto_corr, marker='*', color='red', label='Peaks: {0}'.format(len(auto_corr_peaks)))
        # plt.xlabel('time delay [s]')
        # plt.ylabel('Autocorrelation amplitude')
        # plt.title("AutoCorrelation of the signal {0}".format(k), fontsize=16)
        # plt.legend()
        # # plt.show()
        # plt.show(block = False)
        # print('AutoCorrelation with peaks of the signal {0}'.format(k))
        # plt.pause(5)  # Pauses the program for 10 seconds
        # plt.close('all')

        print('Completed file {}'.format(fp), ', Now going into filtering the signal')

########################################################################################################################
############################################## Filtered Section ########################################################
########################################################################################################################

        # Plotting the smoothed filtered signal acceleration-time graph:
        y_filter = smooth(y, 10)
        # plt.plot(x1, y_filter)
        # plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
        # plt.ylabel('Acceleration (ms^-2)')
        # plt.title('Plot of Smoothed Sensor {0}'.format(k))
        # # plt.show()
        # plt.show(block = False)
        # print('Plot of Smoothed Sensor {0}'.format(k))
        # plt.pause(5)  # Pauses the program for 10 seconds
        # plt.close('all')

        ## Filtered Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)
        # Obtaining the Sampling frequency and time period:
        print('Period:', T_s, 's')
        print('Sampling Frequency: ', f_s, 'Hz')
        f_values_filtered, fft_values_filtered = get_fft_values(y_filter, T_s, N, f_s)

        # Setting plot limits:
        ax = plt.gca()
        ax.set_ylim([min(fft_values_filtered), max(fft_values_filtered)])
        ax.set_xlim([min(f_values_filtered), max(f_values_filtered)])
        amp_index_filtered = np.array(fft_values_filtered)
        amp_index_filtered_max = max(amp_index_filtered)
        amp_index_filtered_min = min(amp_index_filtered)
        amp_index_filtered_delta = (amp_index_filtered_max + abs(amp_index_filtered_min)) / 2

        # Obtaining the amplitude values:
        maxtab, mintab = np.array(peakdet(amp_index_filtered, amp_index_filtered_delta))
        amplitudes3 = maxtab
        y_axis_list_filtered = []
        for e in range(len(amplitudes3)):
            amplitude3 = amplitudes3[e]
            amplitude3final = amplitudes3[e][1]
            y_values_filtered = amplitude3final
            y_axis_list_filtered.append(y_values_filtered)
        x_axis_filtered = np.abs(f_values_filtered)
        x_axis_list_filtered = []
        for o in range(len(y_axis_list_filtered)):
            x_axis_values_filtered = findyaxis(y_axis_list_filtered[o], x_axis_filtered, fft_values_filtered)
            x_axis_list_filtered.append(x_axis_values_filtered)
        peaks_filtered = merge(x_axis_list_filtered, y_axis_list_filtered)
        print('Number of Filtered Peaks Coordinates: ', len(peaks_filtered))
        print('Filtered Peaks Coordinates: ', peaks_filtered)

        # Plotting the amplitude-frequency graph:
        # plt.plot(f_values_filtered, fft_values_filtered, linestyle='-', color='blue')
        # plt.scatter(x_axis_list_filtered, y_axis_list_filtered, marker='*', color='red', label='Peaks: {0}'.format(len(peaks_filtered)))
        # plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]', fontsize=16)
        # plt.ylabel('Amplitude', fontsize=16)
        # plt.title("Filtered Frequency domain of the signal {0}".format(k), fontsize=16)
        # plt.legend()
        # # plt.show()
        # plt.show(block = False)
        # print('Filtered Frequency domain with peaks of the signal {0}'.format(k))
        # plt.pause(5)  # Pauses the program for 10 seconds
        # plt.close('all')

        # Obtaining PSD Filtered values:
        f_values_filtered, psd_values_filtered = get_psd_values(y_filter, T_s, N, f_s)
        amp_psd_index_filtered = np.array(psd_values_filtered)
        amp_psd_index_filtered_max = max(amp_psd_index_filtered)
        amp_psd_index_filtered_min = min(amp_psd_index_filtered)
        amp_psd_index_filtered_delta = (amp_psd_index_filtered_max + abs(amp_psd_index_filtered_min)) / 2
        maxtab, mintab = np.array(peakdet(amp_psd_index_filtered, amp_psd_index_filtered_delta))
        amplitudes_psd_filtered = maxtab
        y_axis_list_psd_filtered = []
        for e in range(len(amplitudes_psd_filtered)):
            amplitude_psd_filtered = amplitudes_psd_filtered[e]
            amplitude_psd_final_filtered = amplitudes_psd_filtered[e][1]
            y_values_psd_filtered = amplitude_psd_final_filtered
            y_axis_list_psd_filtered.append(y_values_psd_filtered)
        x_axis_psd_filtered = np.abs(f_values_filtered)
        x_axis_list_psd_filtered = []
        for o in range(len(y_axis_list_psd_filtered)):
            x_axis_values_psd_filtered = findyaxis(y_axis_list_psd_filtered[o], x_axis_psd_filtered, psd_values_filtered)
            x_axis_list_psd_filtered.append(x_axis_values_psd_filtered)
        psd_peaks_filtered = merge(x_axis_list_psd_filtered, y_axis_list_psd_filtered)
        print('Number of Filtered PSD Peaks Coordinates: ', len(psd_peaks_filtered))
        print('Filtered PSD Peaks Coordinates: ', psd_peaks_filtered)
        print('X-Axis Filtered PSD Amplitudes: ', amplitudes_psd_filtered[:, [0]])
        length_amplitudes_psd_filtered = len(amplitudes_psd_filtered[:, [0]])
        print('Amplitudes PSD filtered length: ', length_amplitudes_psd_filtered)
        if length_amplitudes_psd_filtered > 1:
            # for PSD_Mean in range(length_amplitudes_psd_filtered):
            X_axis_values_psd_mean = mean(x_axis_list_psd_filtered)
            print('Mean Amplitudes PSD filtered: ', X_axis_values_psd_mean)
        else:
            X_axis_values_psd_mean = x_axis_list_psd_filtered

        # Plotting PSD-Frequency filtered graph:
        # plt.plot(f_values_filtered, psd_values_filtered, linestyle='-', color='blue')
        # plt.scatter(x_axis_list_psd_filtered, y_axis_list_psd_filtered, marker='*', color='red', label='Peaks: {0}'.format(len(psd_peaks_filtered)))
        # plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
        # plt.ylabel('PSD [V**2 / Hz]')
        # plt.title("Filtered PSD of the signal {0}".format(k), fontsize=16)
        # plt.legend()
        # # plt.show()
        # plt.show(block = False)
        # print('Filtered PSD with peaks of the signal {0}'.format(k))
        # plt.pause(5)  # Pauses the program for 10 seconds
        # plt.close('all')

        # Obtaining Filtered AutoCorrelation values:
        t_values_filtered, autocorr_values_filtered = get_autocorr_values(y_filter, T_s, N, f_s)
        amp_auto_corr_index_filtered = np.array(autocorr_values_filtered)
        amp_auto_corr_index_filtered_max = max(amp_auto_corr_index_filtered)
        amp_auto_corr_index_filtered_min = min(amp_auto_corr_index_filtered)
        amp_auto_corr_index_filtered_delta = (amp_auto_corr_index_filtered_max + abs(amp_auto_corr_index_filtered_min)) / 2
        maxtab, mintab = np.array(peakdet(amp_auto_corr_index_filtered, amp_auto_corr_index_filtered_delta))
        amplitudes_auto_corr_filtered = maxtab
        y_axis_list_auto_corr_filtered = []
        for e in range(len(amplitudes_auto_corr_filtered)):
            amplitude_auto_corr_filtered = amplitudes_auto_corr_filtered[e]
            amplitude_auto_corr_final_filtered = amplitudes_auto_corr_filtered[e][1]
            y_values_auto_corr_filtered = amplitude_auto_corr_final_filtered
            y_axis_list_auto_corr_filtered.append(y_values_auto_corr_filtered)
        x_axis_auto_corr_filtered = np.abs(t_values_filtered)
        x_axis_list_auto_corr_filtered = []
        for o in range(len(y_axis_list_auto_corr_filtered)):
            x_axis_values_auto_corr_filtered = findyaxis(y_axis_list_auto_corr_filtered[o], x_axis_auto_corr_filtered, autocorr_values_filtered)
            x_axis_list_auto_corr_filtered.append(x_axis_values_auto_corr_filtered)
        auto_corr_peaks_filtered = merge(x_axis_list_auto_corr_filtered, y_axis_list_auto_corr_filtered)
        print('Number of Filtered AutoCorrelation Peaks Coordinates: ', len(auto_corr_peaks_filtered))
        print('Filtered AutoCorrelation Peaks Coordinates: ', auto_corr_peaks_filtered)

        # Plotting AutoCorrelation-Time delay filtered graph:
        # plt.plot(t_values_filtered, autocorr_values_filtered, linestyle='-', color='blue')
        # plt.scatter(x_axis_list_auto_corr_filtered, y_axis_list_auto_corr_filtered, marker='*', color='red', label='Peaks: {0}'.format(len(auto_corr_peaks_filtered)))
        # plt.xlabel('time delay [s]')
        # plt.ylabel('Autocorrelation amplitude')
        # plt.title("Filtered AutoCorrelation of the signal {0}".format(k), fontsize=16)
        # plt.legend()
        # # plt.show()
        # plt.show(block = False)
        # print('Filtered AutoCorrelation with peaks of the signal {0}'.format(k))
        # plt.pause(5)  # Pauses the program for 10 seconds
        # plt.close('all')

########################################################################################################################
############################################## Feature Matrix ##########################################################
########################################################################################################################
        # Forming a feature matrix from frequency, PSD and AutoCorrelation values:
        for DataSizeRow in range(MaxDataSizerow):
            for DataSizeColumn in range(MaxDataSizecolumn):
                DataFrame_Feature = np.array(X_axis_values_psd_mean)
                Data[DataSizeColumn - 1] = DataFrame_Feature
                Data[DataSizeColumn + 1]
                break
        print('Data Frame: ', Data)
    # np.savetxt('DataFrameTestfinal1.txt', Data, delimiter = ' , ')
    # # np.savetxt('DataFrame3.txt', DataFrame, delimiter=' , ')
    # np.savetxt('DataFrameTestfinal2.txt', DataFrame1, delimiter=' , ')
    # np.savetxt('DataFrameTestfinal3.txt', DataFrame2, delimiter=' , ')
    print('Completed both original and filtered signals of file {}'.format(fp))
```

The dataset is from the website link.
Link:  http://users.metropolia.fi/~kullj/JrkwXyZGkhF/wooden_bridge_time_histories/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also, side question, does anyone know how to code Ibrahim time domain technique? If you do, can you provide an explanation with references?

Comment: I tried a different method, however, I get the same result.                                                       Link: https://snakify.org/en/lessons/two_dimensional_lists_arrays/#section_4